# Issue with react-designer package

Tags: reactjs

I was using "react-designer package" and decided to use the code provided in the documentation of the package itself being:

```
import Designer, {Text, Rectangle} from 'react-designer';

class App() {
  state = {
    objects: [
      {type: "text", x: 10, y: 20, text: "Hello!", fill: "red"},
      {type: "rect", x: 50, y: 70, fill: "red"}
    ]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Designer width={250} height={350}
        objectTypes={{
          'text': Text,
          'rect': Rect
        }}
        onUpdate={(objects) => this.setState({objects})}
        objects={this.state.objects} />
    )
  }
}
```

but faced this issue:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `SVGRenderer`.
```

Comment: I hope you have used the correct export with the App component?
I mean using `export default class App()`

Comment: @Harshkurra, yes I am using necessary exports. Sorry, have you tried installing react-designer package? is it fully working in your PC?

Comment: Every version has some problem, 
V 1.1.1 is not getting installed, I saw they have released it today only
V 1.1.0 has a dependency issue at runtime
V 1.0.9 has same problem as above
V 1.0.6 has runtime issue from `radium` library