# How to create image annotation with React

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to create a project allowing a user to upload an image then create annotations thanks to bullet points something like this [image].

I have succeeded with upload image functionality and now trying to figure out with the help of what package is it possible to achieve the image annotation as shown in the above picture. So, tried to use [react-designer](https://react-designer.github.io/react-designer/) package itself but there is a package bug that I can't solve. Has any of you done such image annotation before? if so, what package is it possible for me to use?

Comment: Can you share some code, and share more details on what you are trying to achieve?
also if possible do explain the issue you are facing with the react-designer

Comment: @Harshkurra,  Hi, the problem I faced with react-designer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345246/issue-with-react-designer-package

Comment: @Harshkurra, if I could solve the problem with react-designer, I would be extremely happy :D. Thus, I really need your help

Comment: @Harshkurra, pls any help will be appreciated((

Comment: ok, I am looking into your original problem

Comment: @Harshkurra, yahooo))), the reason for react-designer being good is that it is VERY close to what I want to achieve))